# I want to backup file when the file is replaced by the same file

Tags: windows, backup, minifilter

I want to backup file when the file is replaced by the same file. And I handle it in precreate, but `FltQueryInformationFile` return `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER (c000000d)`, and if I handle it in `postCreate`, `FltQueryInformationFile` return the file size is zero byte. How should I solve it ?

Comment: Can you share some more context? Do you want to run some kind of deamon that hooks into file modifications? Then you need to provide the OS and programming language you'd like to use, and at least some sample code

Comment: used minifilter driver and with windows 7  x86

Comment: File object be passed on to FktQueryInformationFile might be causing the error. Without detail its hard to say further.

Comment: I just want to know if I want to backup file when the file is replaced by the same file,which IRP should I to handle ?